# How should I find an input value matches with the array value JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AI</title>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function myfunction(){
            var arrayy = [
                "Yo",
                "Hello",
                "Greetings",
                "Hey, what can I do for you?",
                "How's Life",
                "What's Up",
            ];
            var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            utterance.text = arrayy[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayy.length)];
            speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
        }
        function myFunctiontwo(){
            var good = [
                "bien",
                "good",
                "badiya",
                "awesome",
                "great",
                "mast",
                "gr8",
            ];
            var a = document.getElementById("line").value;
            var foundPresent = good.indexOf(a) > -1;
            console.log(foundPresent);
            if(foundPresent === true){
                var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
                utterance.text = "great";
                speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
            }
             else {
                var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
                utterance.text = "haw";
                speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="myfunction()">
        <input type="text" id="line" placeholder="hey!" />&nbsp;<button id="submit" id="sumbit" onclick="myFunctiontwo()">GO</button>
        <div id="text"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I write good,bien, badia, awesome, great, mast, gr8, it says good, but when I write good and you, or great and you or any other sentence with the array value in it it says haw.
Is there anyway I can search if the input text contains these as keywords and compare with array(good)? I am a beginner.

Comment: please explain better the desired input and output

Comment: `var foundPresent = good.some(function(word){ return a.indexOf(word) > -1;))`

Comment: `))` should be `})`.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is to convert your input string into an Array of words. So after that, you can check if any of those words match any of the words in your `good` array, as shown:

```js
function myfunction(){
  var arrayy = [
      "Yo",
      "Hello",
      "Greetings",
      "Hey, what can I do for you?",
      "How's Life",
      "What's Up",
  ];
  var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  utterance.text = arrayy[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayy.length)];
  speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}
        
function myFunctiontwo(){
  var good = [
      "bien",
      "good",
      "badiya",
      "awesome",
      "great",
      "mast",
      "gr8",
  ];
  var a = document.getElementById("line").value.split(' ');
  var foundPresent = a.some(elem => good.indexOf(elem) > -1);
  console.log(foundPresent);
  if(foundPresent === true){
      var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      utterance.text = "great";
      speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
  }
   else {
      var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      utterance.text = "haw";
      speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
  }
}

myfunction();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="line" placeholder="hey!" />&nbsp;<button id="submit" id="sumbit" onclick="myFunctiontwo()">GO</button>
<div id="text"></div>
```